# Sum three elements in every row of the matrix - without loops

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I want to write a function `SumThree` which receives a matrix of size `(n x (n+2))` as a numpy array and return a vector `v` which is defined in the following way: `v[i] = A[i,i] + A[i,i+1] + A[i,i+2]`.

**Restrictions:** **No** loops, you **can't** use the function `sum` (`np.sum`)

I did solve it by using recursion and with changing the signature of the function (which should only receive the matrix). But I'm looking for a simpler and more efficient solution.

Something like this (this is what I tried):

```
def sumThree(array, curr=0, i=0, v=[]):
 if curr < array.size
   curr += array.shape[1]
 else
   return v
 count = array.size
 v[i] = array[curr,curr] + array[curr,curr+1] + array[curr,curr+2]
 sumThree(array, curr, i+1, v)
```

**I haven't tried yet but I think this should work:**

```
def sumThree(a):
  return (a.diagonal() + a.diagonal(1) + a.diagonal(2))
```

Comment: The reason why you're being asked to not use a loop is so that you can use numpy vectorization. Recursion is not the correct way to solve this one.

Comment: @rdas Yeah you're right, i'm trying to use some numpy functions. I think `diagonal()` should solve this. reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get specific diagonals (with required offset) by using [numpy.diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)

could you please try this, and see if it works for you?

```py
def sumThree(a):
    return a.diagonal(offset=0) + a.diagonal(offset=1) + a.diagonal(offset=2)
```

here's a full example:

```py
import numpy as np

def sumThree(a):
    return a.diagonal(offset=0) + a.diagonal(offset=1) + a.diagonal(offset=2)


my_arr = np.arange(48).reshape(6,8)
print(my_arr)
print("\n\n\n")
print(sumThree(my_arr))
```

it outputs:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
 [32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47]]




[  3  30  57  84 111 138]
```